# First site in Portuguese site Meta Tags?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I am wondering what the best way to develop a site that is going to be targeted at Brazil. Being from the US i have always used the meta information like below

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
```

Does any of this need to change?

I have seen in a few posts that you should do something like

```
 <html lang="es">
```

and

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Does anyone have any experience with sites from outside the US and what type of meta data is need for all the special Spanish characters.

**UPDATE**

Taking some of the advice below i have realized that this is actually Portuguese not Spanish and have done some research and it looks most sites still use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

And a combination of these

```
<html lang="pt-BR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br">
<meta name="language" content="pt-br" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />
```

Comment: Your first problem is that they don't speak Spanish in Brazil.  They speak Portuguese.

Comment: You should also not entirely rely on the meta tags.  You should create a decent map of all the special characters.  This might help:  http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp860.html

Comment: In addition to this - why don't you just look at the code for some pages that are hosted in Brazil or Portugal?  I can pretty much guarantee that they have all the stuff you are looking for completely in place.

Comment: HAHA Good point on Portuguese my creative department just found that the language in the files are not English and i guess assumed it was Spanish. But not that you say it i did know that :)

Also a good idea on finding a site that is from Brazil

Comment: The question does not even specify what the language in the document is. It seems to be based on an assumption that declaring the language in various ways would have some special effect and would be needed for “all the special Spanish characters”. Moreover, the question has been improperly edited to contain a sort-of an answer, instead of making the *question* clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need any special meta tags.
You can specify the language of the content and the character encoding of the document. But you can (and should) do this for every site, even those with English content.

Assuming HTML5:

You specify the language with the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes). If the whole page is in a certain language, just add it to the `html` element:

```
<html lang="pt-BR"> <!-- for Brazilian Portuguese -->
```

You specify the character encoding with the `meta` element and its [`charset` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-charset):

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- for UTF-8 -->
```

(Of course you need to specify the actual encoding used; so only use the value `utf-8` if your documents use UTF-8.)

Answer (score 2):

*Moving this comment block to answer for credit, as it appears to be accepted.*

Your first problem is that they don't speak Spanish in Brazil. They speak Portuguese.

Just look at the code for some pages that are hosted in Brazil or Portugal? I can pretty much guarantee that they have all the stuff you are looking for completely in place.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer (2022) for this question seems to be lang="pt".

The latest IANA Language Subtag Registry contains only one subtag per language, so there is no longer any ambiguity from pt versus pt-br.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-2or3#answer

Registry: https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry
.